# I'm trying to do a dynamically range offset but i get an error

Tags: excel, function, offset

I've never used this before but i get an error when i try to do a normal offset for dynamically range through the Name Manager

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1)
```

Text in the error: "The formula you typed contains error."

I must be doing something wrong but i dont know what.

Here is my sheet:

```
A1 1 B1 Product1
A2 2 B2 Product2
A3 3 B3 Product3
```

I'm trying to make an offset so i can take the value of the second column in a variable in a macro with the VLookup() function. I'm still not getting fully in this VBA and this macros but i hope you understood what i want to do.

The macro should look something like that:

```
myProductValue = Applications.Worksheet.VLookup("e6", [someOffsetName], 2, 0)
```

So if the first column are the ID's and i type the ID number into cell e6 (for example) to get the value of the second column which refers to the ID given into the cell e6 into the variable "myProductValue"

Comment: Does your version of Excel use the comma as argument separator within formulas, or the semicolon?

Comment: The formula works fine on my Excel (2010 on Windows 7). Are you copying and pasting it? What version of Excel and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on windows 7 and using excel 2010... should i turn on some settings or something like this ?

Comment: @AntonPapazov - Do you have a worksheet named `Sheet1`?

Comment: If you put the following formula in a cell in your worksheet, what error or result do you get: `=ROWS(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1))`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes my worksheet has the same name

Comment: @NickPeranzi i get the same error

I will update the question with my table...

Comment: @AntonPapazov did you see the first comment to this thread?

Comment: Would you kindly respond to my question? If you're not sure what I meant, just ask for clarification.

Comment: And what has this new edit re VBA got to do with it? Is it even relevant to the issue you are facing?

Comment: @XORLX i tried with semicolon and tried with commas both dont work. And the VBA does get nothing with the thing that i ask but i'm just more specific of my task. I gave the reason why i want to make an offset for dynamically range.

Comment: But what do your formulas/functions use in general? Semicolon or comma? For example, would you use: MATCH(A1,B1:B10,0) or MATCH(A1;B1:B10;0)? One of those will give you a "The formula you typed contains an error" message. the other won't (though it may return #N/A).

Comment: The semicolons were the problem :) Thank you very much sorry i lost your time with my mistake. When i tried the first time with semicolons i missed to change it in the last argument about the width... So this is the working offset that catches all my table ->   

=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1; 2)

Comment: @XORLX so if you want reputation post an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your formula looks fine.  It should prompt no error except a few conditions.  I have also listed those in comment for your reference:

> 1)  Your worksheet's name is not "Sheet1" (credit to Scott Holtzman)
>
> 2)  Your Excel might have used semicolon instead of comma as argument
>   separater (credit to XORLX)
>
> 3)  Your formula is placed in column A of the same sheet (i.e. Sheet1), where some excel version will prompt for warning of self referencing (i.e. infinite loop)
>
> 4)  You are actually trying to refers to a range with mentioned formula in Name manager.

More information is needed in order to resolve your issue.  You could also try to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: None of this conditions are the problem. I will update the question for more info